# How to save the system state during windows sleep on vmware Ubuntu 18.0.14 lts?

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, vmware, 18.10

I have a ubuntu running on vmware setup on windows10. Whenever windows goes to sleep or i lock out the windows the programs that am running on ubuntu are not being saved.

Once i login after resuming windows i see that ubuntu is in fresh state without any previous running apps ?

Is there option to achieve the window hibernate like option in ubuntu to save all the running programs state on sleep/hibernate of host OS (windows) ??

Any help is much appreciated . Thanks